# Tor Browser Bundle Single-Hop

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays

I downloaded the Tor source. I could compile it and run it with the changes to the or.h file creating a single hop for better tor speed.

As explain in this topic: [How to decrease number of Tor hops?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/how-to-decrease-number-of-tor-hops)

But after compilation. I don't know how to use the newly compiled and installed Tor without using the Tor bundle. And apparently the tor bundle comes with all the tor and stuff in it. So it doesn't use Single hop.
Soo....

Is there a way to configure the tor bundle to use Single Hop?
OR
How do you make use of a Tor compiled and installed from its tor-0.2.9.10.tar.gz source.

Or can I make changes to the Tor Bundle Source to create single hops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replacing the `tor` binary included with the Tor Browser with the one that you have built would work, e.g.:

`cp ~/tor-0.2.9.10/src/or/tor ~/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor`

Will mean that when Tor Browser starts, it will launch your modified copy of Tor rather than that included with it.

Comment: Awesome! That was simple enough. I feel like there should some guide to that somehwhere. I kept trying to follow the "tor-yfying your applications" guide. Thanks a bunch brother.