# How to control my Tor-Nodes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, guard-node

I know that Tor needs 3 nodes to work, but is there a way to control my node number, mean to add more nodes or subtract nodes.

Comment: No. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChoosePathLength Not unless you are a developer or researcher.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in standard Tor browser.

However you can modify Tor to use a custom amount of hops.

For a 2 hop example see here: https://www.grepular.com/Tor_Circuits_with_Two_Hops_on_Ubuntu

**Note:** You really shouldn't do this since it harms your anonymity. (https://torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChoosePathLength )

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have already changed the number of hops from 3 to 2. but when i'm changing  to 1 hop i can't use the Tor-browser, which means that i can't  see site's. if ill create a private tor network it my works? @bn4t

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience in changing the amount of hops to be able to tell why it doesn't works. But I doubt that it will work when creating a private Tor network without making additional code changes.

Comment: @jonny Don't even think of using one-hop circuits without more source code changes. See https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16805/4894 .